# PHP generated option list only appearing on first Ajax dynamically generated container

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having an issue where my php generated select/option list is not applying to all of my dynamically generated blocks/containers. It only adds the PHP select to the last container/block instance, despite being called for each container. When troubleshooting with alerts it seems to run through all of the iterations prior to adding the containers/blocks and generating the select, hence why it always appears on the last only-

```
n = -1
function addDiv() {
            n++;
```

So, a brief overview -  on page initialize the code will get how many entries are in the database within a certain criteria and apply that number to 'length', which then runs the function addDiv() that many times. Usually, when adding a block one at a time via button it will populate the created block with a Select/list of Options via php in the addDiv() function, however when automating this with a loop ( the initialize() function ) the above issue occurs.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
$.ajax({
            url: 'get-entries.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
                var arrayJson = JSON.parse(data);

                console.log(arrayJson);
                length = arrayJson.length;
                console.log(length);

                for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                 addDiv();
                };

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR) {
                        alert("Error while fetching data");
                        console.log("Error while fetching data: " + jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.statusText + " " + jqXHR.responseText); //improved error logging
                    }
            });
    };
```

here is the addDiv related code with some redactions to make it easier to read.

```
var n = -1;

    function addDiv() {
        n++;

     $.post(  
            "json-option-generator.php",  
        {}                               
        ).done(                          
            function(data)
            {
        $('#selectedcoin' + n).html(data); 
            });

     $("<div class='coinmarketcap fill' id='container" 
     + n + 
     "'><form id='"
     + n +
     "' name='"
     + n +
     "' class='formClass' method='post' action=''><select onchange='mySelect(this)' type='text' class='coinname' id='selectedcoin" 
     + n + 
     "' name='selectedcoin"
     + n +
     //.etc.....
     "' autocomplete='off' value=''><select></select>").appendTo(".main-container"); 

}
```

and finally here is the contents of the PHP file for generating the option list based off of json data -

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("../ticker/full.json");

$decode = json_decode($json, true);
sort($decode);

echo '<select name="coinname">';
    foreach($decode as $a){
        echo "<option value='{$a['id']}'>{$a['name']}</option>";
    }
echo '</select>';
?>
```

I know this is messy and may require a bit of an in depth read through, so I appreciate anyone taking the time to look.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that can help nudge me in the right direction? I have tried breaking the 'addDiv()' calls within initialize() by wrapping 'addDiv()' with a setTimeout function, but no joy.

Comment: because you are using an asynchronous call in `addDiv`, there is a very big chance that all your `for` loop turns are finished when the first result arrives. Then because `n` is "global" (for the function), it has already its final value. What you can do is write a function to wrap your `$.post` call, that takes `n` as argument and stores it as a local var, so the value is not lost.

Comment: Would you be able to write a quick example of this (only using the bare bones code required)? I'm having trouble successfully implementing what you have explained into my select generating `$.post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work with this (I named the arguments differently for comprehension, but `index` and `index_t` can all be named `n`):

```
var n = -1;

function sendToGenerator(index){
    var index_t = index;
    $.post(  
        "json-option-generator.php",  
        {}                               
    ).done(                          
        function(data)
        {
            $('#selectedcoin' + index_t).html(data); 
        }
    );
}

function addDiv() {
    n++;

    sendToGenerator(n);

    $("<div class='coinmarketcap fill' id='container" 
    + n + 
    "'><form id='"
    + n +
    "' name='"
    + n +
    "' class='formClass' method='post' action=''><select onchange='mySelect(this)' type='text' class='coinname' id='selectedcoin" 
    + n + 
    "' name='selectedcoin"
    + n +
    //.etc.....
    "' autocomplete='off' value=''><select></select>").appendTo(".main-container"); 

}
```